# Convert an eloqvent object to an array

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

i want to convert an return from eloquent an array as [1,2,3].

```
$usersList = Aplication::select('user_id')->where('status', '=', -1)->orWhere('status', '=', 0)->get();
$usersList = json_decode($usersList);
```

I try with `array_values($userList)` but the result is:

```
`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#354 (1) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(9)
  }
}
[{"user_id":9}]`
```

My question is hot to transform this return form eloquent array with only that id's of users like `[1,2,3]' not ['userid' => 1, 'userid'=> 2, userid=>3]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `pluck` & `toArray` functions, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pluck the user_id then convert the result to array:

```
$usersList = Aplication::select('user_id')->where('status', '=', -1)->orWhere('status', '=', 0)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
```